# Is there a reason why these bars wont line up in my excel chart?

Tags: excel, graph, charts, bar-chart, excel-charts

So I'm having trouble. I have added two more bars to this bar chart. The blue one in the second picture lines up beautifully with the rest. However, when I add the bronze column the bar just plops itself in front of the others. I don't know how to fix this. Any advice is welcome.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## ♣ SOLVED ♣

- Q: Is there a reason why these bars wont line up in my excel chart?
- A: Yes, there most certainly is

Let me elaborate with an example/screenshots etc. to (hopefully) help you come right with this issue (which, admittedly, has plagued me for some time)...

---

**STEPS**

1. Hover your mouse over any of the bars in the chart and right click to display the context menu with the following set of options:
   [image: Context menu: right click]
2. Now select the option right at the bottom - i.e. "Format Data Series..."
3. This should open the relevant side pane menu bar - *vide-licit* :
   [image: Format Data Series side-pane menu bar]
4. Vary the Series Overlap and Gap Width options to resolve - voila! ☺

---

**EXAMPLES**

- Notice the spacing at the default values Excel has used (-27%, 219% resp.)
  [image: Normal bars]
- Look what happens when I select 0% for both:
  [image: Fat bars]
- Conversely, see what happens for a 'lower' selection re: the 'series overlap' (-50%) [Gap width as before)
  [image]

---

**REFERENCES**

For more detail, tips/tricks - see H. Bradleys blog [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2012/03/28/excel-charts-tips/#:%7E:text=To%20adjust%20the%20overlap%20between,series%20by%20dragging%20towards%20Overlapped.).

---

**LINKS**

For a Google sheets representation (of little value really, as it was raining), see [hee](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VVfsfqJYk36IbOKG8tE1UHBZSJdLj9knF4uPxYgWnYA/edit?usp=sharing)

*Like and subscribe! (i.e. feel free to say thanks via an upvote ☺ - ta!)*